# How Do I Set Parent State Up a Tree?

Tags: reactjs

I need to change the state of parents that are in a tree like structure. For example, think of a search refinement that is a tree. Similar to the `department` refinement you may find on Amazon search.

```
- Level 1
   - Level 2
       - Level 3a
       - Level 3b
```

When `Level 3a` or `Level 3b` is clicked I want to set the state `checked="checked"` all the way up the tree.

I can currently set `Level 2` by passing the function from `Level 2` down to `Level 3a/b` and calling that function `onClick` in the `Level 3a/b` component. Since `Level 2` is not clicked when this occurs, just a state change, I cannot trigger the function for `Level 1`.

I'm wondering if there is a general approach to handling changing state on parents when a nested child component is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I like the "data down actions up" approach.
Having said that, the nested components should have some action passed to them, which upon invocation updates the state.

3 common patters:

1. Prop drilling - drill the event handlers all the way down, from parent to son
2. Use `context API` that provides the state and the actions to change it
3. Some global state (Redux, Recoil, Mobx). One might argue that 2 also applies for this item.